# Is there a special name in Korean for adverbs like '반짝반짝', '흔들흔들', '빙글빙글'?

Tags: vocabulary

There seems to be a group of 'doubled' words in Korean that often describe how something looks or moves, e.g. :

반짝반짝  - 'twinkle' or 'sparkle'
흔들흔들  - 'shake' or 'wobble'
빙글빙글  - to go round and round

Is there a special name in Korean for these kind of words?
(Further examples more than welcome - I really like these words!)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

They are mimetic words. They're called 음성상징어, and can be further classified into two categories:

1. [의성어](https://namu.wiki/w/%EC%9D%98%EC%84%B1%EC%96%B4) are words that reflect the sound of something (phonomimes / onomatopoeia):

> 후루룩 (the sound of slurping)
>
> 쨍그랑 (the sound of a metal dish falling)

2. [의태어](https://namu.wiki/w/%EC%9D%98%ED%83%9C%EC%96%B4) are words that reflect the "shape" of something (for example it's movement or feeling) (phenomimes).  Your examples (반짝반짝, 흔들흔들, 빙글빙글) all belong to this category.  Some others:

> 성큼성큼 ("shape" of walking with large steps)
>
> 데굴데굴 (rolling "shape")
>
> 깡총깡총 (hopping "shape", especially rabbits)

More examples [here](http://blog.daum.net/_blog/BlogTypeView.do?blogid=0JoTY&articleno=2831533&categoryId=0&regdt=20120826052328).  And a [comedy program spoofing 의성어 words](http://m.tvcast.naver.com/v/890748).

All these words are adverbs (부사), but usually these words can be used as verbs by "halving" them and adding the ending -거리다 (or sometimes -대다):

> 빙글거리다, 흔들거리다, 흔들대다